# What is the meaning of "last" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "last" in the following sentence?

> Whiptail was first. He set sail so fast! But his tail whipped the sail
>   and then he was **last**. 
>   Little Dale saw it all. So he got out of his boat to carry Whiptail
>   across the moat.
>   Dean had a boat that looked like a bean. It would not float. It began
>   to lean. Out fell Dean! And there was Dale, to take him across to be
>   with Whiptail.

? (Source: The Crossing by Foster & Erickson Illustrations by Kerri Gifford)

Does "he was last" mean "he was the lowest rank" ? Or does "he was last" mean "he was spoiled the race' ?

Does "last" in the sentence mean "lowest rank" or "spoiled" ?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked up *last* in a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: I'm reading the story book, and I'm not sure that his place is the last(=the lowest rank, bottom). I think that you want to say that(last=the lowest rank, bottom). Do I understand what you mean to say to me? but, In the story book, after Whiptail fell into the water, Dean fell into the water and Dale saved Dean. Dale took Dean across to be with Whiptail. After that, Others felled into the water, Dale saved others. If so, Was Whiptail the lowest rank? or Was Dean the lowest rank? ... Anyway, does "last" in the sentence mean "lowest rank" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whiptail was first, he set sail so fast.

This implies that there is some kind of race. It might not be an actual organized one - maybe he was just sailing ahead of the others.

> But his tail whipped the sail and then he was last.

He broke the sail of the boat, which meant that he was after the others in order.